# Confusion about stroke and fill for SVG path animations?

Tags: inkscape, svg, animation, javascript

I'm trying to replicate this SVG animation: [Codepen-original](https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/ZeEpgd) but with my SVG logo.
Here is the same codepen with my SVG logo: [Codepen-with-my-SVG](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBLGeg).

I'm new to dealing SVG's and started learning and using Inkscape.

Two concepts are really confusing me right now, In this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841736/how-to-get-a-proper-svg-code) it is mentioned that you need to use two properties to animate an SVG path: stroke-dasharray & stroke-dashoffset.

But what i want to achieve is the same kind of animation as shown in the codepen however i want my logo to fill with its original color which includes some gradients, so i don't know how the strokes come into play with what i want to do and how i should alter my SVG logo in Inkscape.

I know you guy's have to take your time to look at the codepens i provided to understand what i want to do, so i appreciate your time in advance and really appreciate any help for me to understand how this is supposed to be done.

Comment: Would this Inkscape extension be helpful: https://gitlab.com/Moini/ink_line_animator/ ?

Comment: Ah, sorry. For animating fills, the dashoffset will not help at all. Try to use a moving mask, or a moving clip, or opacity, for putting the fill in.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Moini, I will look into -Moving clips- and see what i can do, still trying to figure this out, I'm sure it's actually something very simple but only if you know it :).   Basically i just want the logo to fill in from bottom-up or random points from nothing.

Comment: @Moini From what i have gathered so far, I'm assuming that i can use something like a moving mask or clip to replicate the effect but i think i have to create separate masks/clips to expose different parts/objects of my logo?

Comment: For 'bottom-up-filling', I think a single clip should be sufficient. If you fill from random points, more will be needed. Depending on what you want, a moving object which is clipped might work, too (not sure how).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Moini I actually ended up going for a morph animation which is much nicer than what i had in mind, it was just too complicated to figure out at the moment.